# Extract arguments from python script

Tags: python, argparse, optparse

let me explain what I have in mind to do in order to give you some context.
I have a bunch of python scripts ( that use argpars or optpars ) and their outputs can be usually on the consolle in json, plaint text or csv format.

I would like to build an webapp ( angular + node for instance) that generates automatically a web page for each of my script including some input box for any of the argument needed by the python script in order to run them form the UI.

I do not want to write, for each python script, the list and type of arguments that they needs to be run, but I am looking for an automatic way to extract such list form each python script itself.

I can try to parse the -h output for each of the script or parse the script itself ( add_option) but it maybe error prone.

Are you aware of any tools/script/module that allow me to do it automatically?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Assuming that each script supports `-h`, maybe [`docopt`](http://docopt.org/) could parse the result.

Comment: @Robᵩ Thanks, but it looks more an alternative to argparse ect..

Comment: You misunderstand. I mean that you should run `somescript -h`, capture the output, pass that output to `docopt`'s parser, and use the resulting data structure to generate your HTML. You would not be using `doctopt` as it was intended.

Comment: Docopt makes the options definition be the -h output, so it will help where argparse would be prone to inconsistencies.

Comment: @Robᵩ Cool idea but, I just made a test, and it is working so and so for me, for instance

"""test.py
usage: spyder.py [-h] [-i INPUT] [-o OUTPUT]

optional arguments:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  -i INPUT, --input INPUT
                        Input log file
  -o OUTPUT, --output OUTPUT
                        Output

"""

Is parsed as:

{'--help': False,
 '--input': None,
 '--output': None}

would be cool to get the help itself too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `inspect` module will help here:

```
>>> import inspect
>>> def example_function(a, b, c=1234):
        pass
>>> inspect.getargspec(example_function)
ArgSpec(args=['a', 'b', 'c'], varargs=None, keywords=None, defaults=(1234,))
```

Comment: The `plac` package (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/plac) uses `inspect` like this to create a parser that can run such a function.  It creates arguments that correspond to the functions arguments.  But I don't think that helps with inspecting a script that is already using `argparse`.

Answer (score 1):

You may have to elaborate on what access you have to the scripts and their parsers.  Are they black boxes that you can only invoke with `-h` and get back a help or usage message, or can you inspect the `parser`?

For example when using `argparse`, you make a `parser`, assign it some attributes and create argument `Actions`.  Those action objects are collected in a list, `parser._actions`.

Look at `parser.format_help` and `parser.format_usage` methods to see what values are passed to the help formatter to create the string displays.

Apart from examining the `argparse.py` file, I'd suggest creating a parser in an interactive session, and examine the objects that are created.